# Selection of filtered rows from tables in different directories based on constraints to be converted into an Excel file

Tags: sql, windows-7, visual-foxpro

I want to copy a filtered list of rows for `ctw.code1` and `dl.name` fields to an excel file which is created primarily based on equality of `lower(subdir)` fields in two tables from different directories. I am unsure whether `Inner Join` or `Select` command would be better for this task. Currently I am trying to use `Select`, but *VFP* displays the `Subdir is not unique and must be qualified` error.

```
SELECT ctw.code1, dl.name FROM e:\ctwd ctw, d:\del dl where (ctw.lower(subdir) = dl.lower(subdir) AND (ctw.code1 >=30 OR ctw.code2 >= 30))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INNER JOIN isn't a command. It's a clause of the SELECT command. It looks like your problem is that you're applying functions too soon. This version should work:

```
SELECT ctw.code1, dl.name 
FROM e:\ctwd ctw, d:\del dl 
WHERE lower(ctw.subdir) = lower(dl.subdir)
AND (ctw.code1 >=30 OR ctw.code2 >= 30)
```

That said, if you're in VFP 5 or later, it's better to use INNER JOIN to match the records from different tables because it makes it easier for other people to understand how your query works. That version would look like this:

```
SELECT ctw.code1, dl.name
FROM e:\ctwd ctw 
JOIN d:\del dl ON lower(ctw.subdir) = lower(dl.subdir)
WHERE (ctw.code1 >=30 OR ctw.code2 >= 30)
```

Note that the INNER keyword is optional; if you want, you can add it in front of JOIN.